# Detect if server response is slow and show alert on Javascript Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I would like to know if there is a way that if my request takes more than 20 seconds, I can show an alert alerting users of an error in the API. So they can refresh the page or come back later.

Something like response.status.

I do NOT need setTimeout and AbortController. Just detect response and trigger the alert.

```
const envSoli = async () => {
    try {
      let peticion = await fetch("data.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        cache: "no-cache"
      });
      let oreen = await peticion.json();

        switch (oreen.enviando) {
          case -1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
  
          case 1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
        
          case 2:
                chenille++;
                document.getElementById("div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
                nieva++;
                updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
                tvmit_dieUp();
                break;
  
          case 3:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
              tvmit_liveUp();
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              break;
      }
  
        OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  envSoli();
```

Comment: Why are you so explicitly *against* `setTimeout`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `setTimeout` to set the `timer` to 20 sec, and after the `fetch` request, if the request takes less than 20 seconds, clear the `timeout`

```
const envSoli = async () => {
    try {
      let timeId = setTimeout(() => alert('The request take more than 20 sec'), 20 * 1000); // 20 sec
      let peticion = await fetch("data.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: "ajax=1&do=check&lista=" + encodeURIComponent(leray[chenille]),
        headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        cache: "no-cache"
      });
      clearTimeout(timeId)
      let oreen = await peticion.json();

        switch (oreen.enviando) {
          case -1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.cat + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
  
          case 1:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div1").append(oreen.dog + "<br />");
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              tvmit_wrongUp();
              break;
        
          case 2:
                chenille++;
                document.getElementById("div2").append(oreen.sky + "<br />");
                nieva++;
                updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
                tvmit_dieUp();
                break;
  
          case 3:
              chenille++;
              document.getElementById("div3").append(oreen.water + "<br />");
              tvmit_liveUp();
              updateProgress(chenille, leray.length);
              break;
      }
  
        OKTY(leray, chenille, aarsh, nieva);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  envSoli();
```